# CSS Toggle not displaying changes

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, toggle

I wrote a simple code to change font and color of text on google and it worked but when I tried to implement it into a toggle on / off switch, the changes don't appear.

I used ChatGPT to get some assistance in error reduction and general knowledge of what I did wrong (aware that it does give incorrect information) but after running quite a number of iterations through the prompts, it no longer has any substantial changes that it can detect.

```
//Get the URL
const site = window.location.hostname

//Function to add custom CSS
let customStyle;
const Add_Custom_Style = css => customStyle = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("style")).innerHTML = css;
const Remove_Custom_Style = () => customStyle.remove();

//Function to change CSS
function changeCSS(){
    //Function for Google.com
    if (site.includes("google.com")){
        Add_Custom_Style(`
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Advent+Pro:wght@300&display=swap');

        * {
            font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif !important; 
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        a {
            color: #b0dff4 !important; 
            font-size: 140%;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            color: #b0dff4 !important;
        }
        `)
    }
}

//Function to remove CSS
function removeCSS(){
    customStyle.remove();
}

//Toggle function on off
window.onload = function() {
    const cssToggleBtn = document.getElementById("togBtn");

    cssToggleBtn.addEventListener("change", function(){
        if(cssToggleBtn.checked){
            changeCSS();
        }
        else{
            removeCSS();
        }
    });
};
```

This is the code I am currently using. If I missed something or there is a blatant error, please point it out. Thank you!

Comment: _Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence_ This error means invalid syntax or it is NOT JavaScript. There is no `=\>` in JS.

Comment: I think the `backslash` was added in when I was formatting the code for posting. Remove those from the constants. The only error I'm receiving is for null parameters on the event listener for the cssToggleBtn. Apologies for the misinformation.

Comment: *Removed the backslashes and code now should only have an error for null parameters. Also additional information to add is that this is for a chrome extension. The manifest and html run fine so the only place I can imagine the error being is in the javascript file. Permissons and content scripts are both included.

Comment: @vee would you mind taking a look at the code again?

Comment: _Uncaught TypeError: cssToggleBtn is null_ because there is no HTML at all. Try to paste your code into somewhere that you can run and see the result (example jsfiddle.net ) and make sure that it is relevant code and can reproduce your problem and then update them into your question.

Comment: This code `if (site.includes("google.com")){` means `site` constant that get current URL must be **google.com**. How can it possible that you run from your domain but it will be **google.com**?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Get the URL
const site = window.location.hostname

//Function to add custom CSS
let customStyle;
const Add_Custom_Style = (css) => {
  customStyle = document.createElement("style")
  document.head.appendChild(customStyle).innerHTML = css;
}
const Remove_Custom_Style = () => customStyle.remove();

//Function to change CSS
function changeCSS(){
    //Function for Google.com
    //if (site.includes("google.com")){// Are you sure? Running this under google.com domain?
        Add_Custom_Style(`
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Advent+Pro:wght@300&display=swap');

        * {
            font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif !important; 
            color: #fff !important;
        }

        a {
            color: #b0dff4 !important; 
            font-size: 140%;
        }

        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
            color: #b0dff4 !important;
        }
        `)
    //}
}

//Function to remove CSS
function removeCSS(){
    customStyle.remove();
}

//Toggle function on off
window.onload = function() {
    const cssToggleBtn = document.getElementById("togBtn");

    cssToggleBtn.addEventListener("change", function(){
        if(cssToggleBtn.checked){
            changeCSS();
        }
        else{
            removeCSS();
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<h1>Demo</h1>
<p>
  <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
</p>
<label>
  <input id="togBtn" type="checkbox">
  Toggle.
</label>
```

`if (site.includes("google.com")){` means `site` constant that get current URL must be google.com.
Are you sure that you running this under Google domain?

You have `customStyle` variable and call to this with `.remove()` to remove `<style>` element but you assign it incorrectly.

You already delcared `Remove_Custom_Style` as a function to remove `<style>` element on `customStyle` variable. So, you don't have to declare `removeCSS()` function to do the same thing again.
Choose one!

Comment: Yes the /if/ statement for google is correct. This line of code allows the extension to change the text throughout the entire page. After reviewing my mistakes and testing your updated version of the code the toggle did work but now I realized that the checkbox is not remaining "checked" after the extension is exited. I will work on fixing that issue myself but thank you for helping me past this hurdle.